# Assistance with finding the found parameters in a model

Tags: python, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I have a loop that finds the ultimate parameters to run a model, but I am having trouble getting which parameter that was found and used to run through the data.  I am looking for an adjustment to this code that reports the best params.  This code takes about 20 minutes to run on a 1500 rows and 200 column numeric data set.

Here is waht I have that generates the ultimate results.

```
def test(models, data, iterations = 100):
    results = {}
    for i in models:
        r2_train = []
        r2_test = []
        for j in range(iterations):
            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data[X],data[Y], test_size= 0.2)
            r2_test.append(metrics.r2_score(y_test,models[i].fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)))
            r2_train.append(metrics.r2_score(y_train, models[i].fit(X_train,  y_train).predict(X_train)))
        results[i] = [np.mean(r2_train), np.mean(r2_test)]
    return pd.DataFrame(results)

lasso_params = {'fit__alpha':[0.005, 0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.06]}
ridge_params = {'fit__alpha':[550, 580, 600, 620, 650]}

pipe1 = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures()), ('fit', linear_model.LinearRegression())])
pipe2 = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures()), ('fit', linear_model.Lasso())])
pipe3 = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures()), ('fit', linear_model.Ridge())])

models3 = {'OLS': pipe1, 
'Lasso': GridSearchCV(pipe2, param_grid=lasso_params).fit(train[X],train[Y]).best_estimator_ , 
'Ridge': GridSearchCV(pipe3, param_grid=ridge_params).fit(train[X],train[Y]).best_estimator_,}
```

This is how I would call it:

```
test(models3, train)
```

This is what is generated:

```
       OLS       Lasso       Ridge
0   1.000000    0.914186    0.985494
1   0.700401    0.877555    0.867068
```

I would like to also get the parameters that were fond to generate the results.
Thank you, in advance for any assistance and clarification.

Comment: Do you want the parameters or the _hyper_-parameters? i.e. the coefficients of the models, or the best `alpha` from your CV? If you want the best hyperparameters you can use `best_params_` on your `GridSearchCV` objects, which you should probably save somewhere since at present you are only saving the best_estimator and throwing way all the other info from your CV and gridsearch. You could also call `get_params` on your `best_estimator_`. If you want the parameters then call `coef_` on you estimators.

Comment: @Dan, how should I get the hyperparameters that were used to generate the results so I can use them directly to train my models?

Comment: I already answered that...?? best_params_ or get_params(). It's pretty clear in the sklearn docs on GridsearchCV if you're still confused

Comment: no, it was not working the way I was expecting.  I know how to find the actual required params.  I needed to know the ones that were used in my code.  But, after reading your reply, I was able to figure it out by simply printing models3 to screen and found the param used to generate the values.  Tks